# MacOS: programmatically finding serial ports?

Tags: ios, macos, serial-port

Is there a library call in MacOS to list the available serial ports and the settings of each?  Hopefully something that might port to iOS at some time with minimal difficulty.

I would prefer not to `system("ls /dev/tty.*")` and `system("stty ...")` if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use IOKit calls to find serial ports.

See: [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/WorkingWSerial/WWSerial_SerialDevs/SerialDevices.html) and [Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SerialPortSample/Introduction/Intro.html)