# How do I programmatically detect the serial ports on a Mac with C++?

Tags: c++, macos, serial-port, detect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MacOS: programmatically finding serial ports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632558/macos-programmatically-finding-serial-ports)

I am trying to programmatically detect the serial ports (devices) on a Mac with C++.  The examples I'm finding all assume that you know the device name.  For example:

```
int d = open("/dev/tty.usbserial-A4001nU7", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
```

An often recommended way is to use ls /dev/tty.* or ls /dev/cu.* at the Terminal command line. But I need to do this programmatically.  All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: how about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632558/macos-programmatically-finding-serial-ports

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch On Linux perhaps.  This question is tagged MacOSX.

Comment: @gunda that seems to answer this exactly.  The documentation shows how to programatically query all serial ports **and** shows how to get the device name for each.

Comment: @H2CO3 that was in response to a now deleted comment that suggested the OP had a look at udev

Comment: gunda's post indeed pointed me to an SO question with information to solve my problem.  I upvoted the question and correct answer.